# is it worthwhile to zip a big array before sending it to a client

Tags: web, zip, unzip

Web site loads a big array (70,000 elements, each a line of text) at present from a file as a script.

1. is it worth zipping it (reduces size from 2Mb by a factor of 6) and unzipping in the client?
2. If so what is the simplest way to do it?

I don't know whether sending long data takes more time than unzipping in typical cases.